# SQL Azure Database Build Fail - Master Key Must Be Created Before DB Scoped Credential

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-sql-database

I've imported an Azure SQL DB into VS so i can work in Azure Devops with it.
I'm getting this error when i try to build the DB:

`SQL71589: Master Key must be created before a database scoped credential`

The DB has a master key, which was created before the user, credential, and external data source which uses it.

I've tried importing into VS with just the master key and no DB Scoped cred, and get no error, then when i create the cred and load it the error comes back. So it seems to be with the creation of the cred.

Also when i click into the error it says there are syntax errors on my cred script, but I've checked against MS docs and it seems fine.

I've tried dropping and recreating in this order the master key, user, credential and external data source.

Seems to be a couple of threads here about this but they haven't helped so far.

I'm using VS 2019 v16.5.4

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Open the file that caused the error. Add the creation of Master Key to the top of the file before the Scoped Credential and save it. After the change the content of the file will look like below:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION
    BY PASSWORD = '{Your Password}'
GO

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [Your Credential]
    WITH IDENTITY = N'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE';
```

Build the project, the build should now be successful.